# HTTP 400 Unable to create record: The AudioOnly flag is not supported for the Room type Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

When I am creating P2P and Go rooms I am getting error  `[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The AudioOnly flag is not supported for the Room type Twilio` But there is no AudioOnly Flag in my code.

Clueless. Please help.

My Code:

```
   $token = env("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
   $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
$room = $twilio->video->v1->rooms
                          ->create([
                                       "uniqueName" => $roomName,
                                       "type"=>"peer-to-peer"
                                   ]
                          );

                print($room->sid);
                print($room->type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After surfing the 100s of articles and brainstorming. Finally found the reason that Group Video set to AudioOnly from [Console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/video/manage/room-settings). Now changed the AudioOnly to false, also changed the configuration to P2P as per my requirement.

But problem in Twilio Console is that its using settings of Group Room from even if its not active option in Room Type in Room Tology.